# what shell is used by the system command on matlab

Tags: matlab

System commands can be run on Matlab using the `system()` syntax. In a unix environment, what shell does matlab choose for executing system commands? The first entry of `/etc/shells`? Can the default behavior be changed? I am looking for a general solution that will apply to all system calls rather than one that involves forking a child process with the shell of interest as in `system('/bin/ksh <command>')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html#btnr9rs-1)  says,

> On UNIX, MATLAB uses a shell program to execute the given command. It determines which shell program to use by checking environment variables on your system. MATLAB first checks the MATLAB_SHELL variable, and if either empty or not defined, then checks SHELL. If SHELL is also empty or not defined, MATLAB uses /bin/sh.

MATLAB's system command uses MATLAB_SHELL or SHELL, or /bin/sh. You can change the default shell by setting environment variable MATLAB_SHELL or SHELL.

For example, if you choose MATLAB_SHELL, before launching MATLAB, you need to set

```
setenv MATLAB_SHELL /bin/ksh
```

in csh, tcsh.Or,

```
export MATLAB_SHELL="/bin/ksh"
```

in bash.

Then, MATLAB will use /bin/ksh with system command.

If you use /bin/ksh every time, it's better to set MATLAB_SHELL in your ~/.bashrc and so on.